# How to finding matching values in multiple unlists of strings?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, strsplit

I have two datasets:

```
#df1:
Gene   interactors
ACE      BRCA, HER2
NOS       NA, NA
P53       NA
CDON      TGBP

df2:
Gene   interactors
AGT      NOS, HER2
NPKB     CDON
P70      GPC
IK       TGBP
```

I am looking to identify genes in df1 which are listed as interactors under df2 and identify genes in df1 with interactors that match interactors in df2

Outputting:

```
Gene   interactors     matched_gene_interactor   matched_interactor_interactor
ACE      BRCA, HER2         FALSE                        TRUE                      
NOS       NA, NA            TRUE                         FALSE
P53       NA                FALSE                        FALSE
CDON      TGBP              TRUE                         TRUE

#ACE has an interactor (HER2) in both df1 and df2
#NOS matches itself as an interactor in df2
#CDON matches itself as an interactor in df2 and as having an interactor (TGBP) in both df1 and df2
```

I've been able to code to get the `matched_gene_interactor` column with:

```
df1$matched_gene_interactor <-  df1$Gene %in% unlist(strsplit(df2$interactors, ", "))
```

but I am stuck on getting the second `matched_interactor_interactor` column

I have tried a few things but haven't found how to get it to the point of having the second column that I want, for example:

```
df1interactors <-  unlist(strsplit(df1$interactors, ", "))
df2interactors <-  unlist(strsplit(df2$interactors, ", "))
matched_interactor_interactor <-  df1interactors %in% df2interactors
```

How do I match against two datasets with unlisted string splits? I have a biology background so haven't been sure where to start.

example input data:

```
df1:

structure(list(Gene = c("ACE", "NOS", "P53", "CDON"), interactors = c("BRCA, HER2", 
"NA, NA", NA, "TGBP")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

df2:

structure(list(Gene = c("AGT", "NPKB", "P70", "IK"), interactors = c("NOS, HER2", 
"CDON", "GPC", "TGBP")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split `interactors` of `df2` on comma and for each row check if any value of `interactors` from `df1` is present in it.

```
temp <- unlist(strsplit(df2$interactors, ', '))
df1$matched_interactor_interactor <- sapply(strsplit(df1$interactors, ', '), 
                                      function(x) any(x %in% temp))

df1
#   Gene interactors matched_gene_interactor matched_interactor_interactor
#1:  ACE  BRCA, HER2                   FALSE                          TRUE
#2:  NOS      NA, NA                    TRUE                         FALSE
#3:  P53        <NA>                   FALSE                         FALSE
#4: CDON        TGBP                    TRUE                          TRUE
```

---

If `df2$interactors` is not very big you can also do this without splitting `df1$interactors` by creating a dynamic regex pattern :

```
grepl(paste0('\\b', temp, '\\b', collapse = '|'), df1$interactors)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```